# KC Finder - Uploading/browsing the images not working in CiviCRM 5.9.1

Tags: civievent, drupal, images, kcfinder, upload

I am using CiviCRM 5.9.1 and Drupal 7.6

I am creating a new event. adding the image to it by using CKEditor. when I tried to browse images/ upload the image. The error is coming.  Please refer to the screenshot for the error.
[image]

I followed the previous question regarding this KCFinder. I applied the available patch that is for civi 4.6. That one also didn't work.

I checked file permission and drupal uploading file permission. It is fine.

Please give suggestion how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two `civicrm.settings.php` files - or at least that `CIVICRM_DSN` is already defined.  If you remove the extra `civicrm.settings.php` this problem should resolve itself.

Comment: G I have checked, I don't have two civicrm.settings.php file. But I Have found civicrm.settings.php.template file. Do I need to have that or delete it?

Comment: No, that doesn't need to be deleted.